# How to fix switching to jQuery library, each time when I am trying run my code

Tags: jquery, html

When I am trying to run certain function SOMETIMES I am getting switching to js library file, without any alert about mistake. I just can't continue run my code.

And I can't understand why I am getting this not always (if it's my mistake), and just sometimes.

1. I changed cdn jQuery few times
2. I changed jQuery selectors few times
3. I tried with different build function (appendTo, append)
4. My code looks clean, and I didn't find any solutions in internet

Code:

```
function createDiv() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        var someDiv = $("<div/>");
        someDiv.appendTo($("#container"));
    }
    console.log("12 div, were created");
}
```

createDiv()

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to describe.  What specifically isn't working?  In what way are you observing a failure of this code?

Comment: Are you debugging your code? if yes then use step over button not step into the button. Step into button will step into jquery library where you call jquery functions.

Comment: Might be a timing issue, e.g. if you execute `createDiv()` before the DOM has loaded and the elements are available. Could you show us where you execute the function? Is it wrapped in `$().ready()` or add the end of the `<body>`?